# Significance of the Magnificent Seven reference in The Nest

Tags: analysis, reference, the-nest, the-magnificent-seven

At the beginning of [*The Nest (org.: Nid de guêpes)*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0280990/), when *Santino*'s crew drives in their car to prepare the robbery, *Santino* and *Nasser* start whistling the title melody of [*The Magnificent Seven*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0054047/) and the rest of the crew joins them (and this whistled version is also played again at the beginning of the end credits). Apart from just being a very famous melody and the general purpose of loosening up the slightly stressed situation, **is there any further meaning to this melody or any further connection to *The Magnificent Seven* and its story/motives in *The Nest* or this scene in particular?**

(I should add that I haven't seen *The Magnificent Seven* and have only rough knowledge about its plot.)

Comment: I have to admit, I'm tempted to down-vote this simply because you haven't seen The Magnificent Seven ;)

Answer (score 1):

The movie is considered to be an "urban western", with its central good guy/bad guy shootouts a la "Gunfight at the OK Corral".  There is also the theme of a group of bad guys becoming the good guys, or at least blurring the line between good and bad, which is exactly what happens in The Magnificent Seven.  Coupled together, having these criminals whistle the theme to said movie lets you know upfront that the movie has its roots in American Western cinema, and it's a bit of a tip of the hat to that genre.